# Package Manager Error; Permission denied while reading sources.list.d for Spotify Client

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources, cache, spotify

I'm new to Ubuntu (moved from Windows) and have a couple issues. This post is just about one, though.

I tried installing spotify according to the [website instructions](https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/linux/) but my wifi went down midway. I didn't think this was going to be an issue, however I now have a Giant red Circle with a Line through it on my desktop that says:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: ' Error: Opening the cache (E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list-ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied), E:The list of sources could not be read.)'.
>   This usually means that your installed packages have unment dependencies

So, I tried doing `sudo apt-get install -f` but nothing really changed. I then did a couple `sudo apt-get clean` / `sudo apt-get update` / `sudo apt-get upgrade` along with hard restarts, but the Red Circle is still sitting there. I then decided two things: to launch the program from the terminal and to look at the sources.list.d file.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
------------------------------------
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Note: I had to run `sudo vim` to read the file. When running, just `vim`, the file was completely blank. I'm thinking about just changing the permissions of this file with `chmod` so that all can read it, if that's what's causing the problem, but i'm not sure if that's a 'safe' thing to do.

And, these are the error messages I get when running spotify from the terminal:

> [0719/184934:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(752)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
>   [0719/184935:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(752)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak

It seems to run fine, but there aren't any options (file / edit / etc) on the top of the window pane for me to go offline and stuff. I'm not sure if that's because the spotify-client is still in development on Ubuntu, or if I'm really missing those dependencies / features.

Anyways, thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate any advice.

Comment: A quick tip, don't change permissions or owners of files that you haven't created and/or are owned by root.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured it wasn't a good idea, so I didn't do it, it was just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Spotify and reinstall it...

In `terminal`...

- sudo apt-get purge spotify-client
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install spotify-client

**Update #1:**

In `terminal` do `sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

See https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web-Player/Error-quot-Could-not-load-cef-extensions-pak-quot/m-p/1316104#M153712

```
CEF stands for Chromium Embedded Framework, I downloaded it, 
found the file and just copied it into the Spotify-folder. 
You can find the file here: 

http://www.filedropper.com/cefextensions

No file in this link; but this solves the problem:

https://github.com/AtomicGameEngine/CEF3Binaries/blob/master/Linux/Resources/cef_extensions.pak

try

find / -name spotify

I found mine in /usr/share

You can then

sudo cp ~/Downloads/cef_extensions.pak /usr/share/spotify

assuming Downloads is where you downloaded the file and you 
found spotify in the same place.



Also, if you're on linux, you're going to need the file in the 
github link above, courtesy of Sharlotte.
```

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately the notification from Package Manager, or whatever is still there. (Sorry for the late response, and thank you so much for your help).

Comment: Start `synaptic` and click the `reload` icon and tell me about any errors you see. Also, in `terminal` show me `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`.

Comment: Interesting, um I'm sorry if I'm being really dumb, so here's an update:

After installing and reloading synaptic it says that there are no errors:
`0 broken. 0 to install/upgrade, 0 to remove`

And my spotify.list isn't a directory, but rather a single file, so the output of the `ls` command is:
`-rw------- 1 root root 50 Jul 19 18:28 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

The red-circle symbol with the white line is still there on my notifications and it still is displaying the spotify error though which is really odd.

Comment: In `terminal` do `sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`. Reboot. Try my answer again.

Comment: I rebooted and the error symbol is gone! Unfortunately on launch spotify still has errors, but I don't think the two are that related. I might go back to your answer for good measure just to see what happens.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: See https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web-Player/Error-quot-Could-not-load-cef-extensions-pak-quot/m-p/1316104#M153712